# How to add .htaccess file to my html code

Tags: .htaccess

I cannot get a video to play in internet explorer 11 through my iis web page. The video player just displays, "**INVALID SOURCE**" It's a screen capture that I have encoded as .Mp4 I found this comment to fix it:

"Add this line (specific for IE) to your .htaccess file"

Can someone show me where I would add this line to my HTML code as I am just learning this. The screen capture video does play in Chrome and firefox.

Comment: Are you using apache http server? If yes, create a file in your application root folder with name  `.htaccess`.

Comment: I am just learning all this. No, I'm running iis on a test server that's running 2008r2. I have created my own website in iis. Also, when you say "application root folder", do you mean the folder that I have my html and the content files?

Comment: We need more information here, like what library you are using, if it is a ASP.NET project, etc..

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I am new to all this. What do you mean by LIBRARY?

Comment: show us your code where you add this video

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't even know how to add the html to the comment. When I pasted the html into the comment box, it says, " too long by 775 characters".

Comment: How can I add the html code?

Comment: just paste the part where your video are added.

Comment: <video id="test.mp4" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4 " />
  <source src="test_VP8.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="test_libtheora.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

Comment: Check this: http://madskristensen.net/post/prepare-webconfig-for-html5-and-css3 . You should add that to your web.config file.

Comment: FWIW You can't "add this line to your .htaccess file" if you are using IIS to serve your pages. .htaccess is a per-directory Apache config file, IIS does not support this (without additional third party paid extensions).

Comment: I added the xml code from the link you provided. When I got to C:\windows\Microsoft.net, there were two framework folders, I tried the framework64 first, then the newest version, then the config folder. I found the web config file, and I added the code underneath the first system.web tag. It did not work. I then tried the framework folder. that did not work either. Did I do this correctly? Is there anything else I can try?